# Why is gradle build successful even without required dependency?

Tags: java, gradle

I have no `build.gradle` file, so therefore I also have no dependencies specified.

Somehow, gradle successfully builds a project containing this file with the Apache Commons dependencies:

```java
package demo;

import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.InterpolatingMicrosphere;
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.UnitSphereRandomVectorGenerator;

public class Library {
    public Library() {
        var d = new InterpolatingMicrosphere(3, 0, 0d, 0d, 0d, new UnitSphereRandomVectorGenerator(3));
    }
}
```

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 809ms`

If I purposefully introduce an error to check the file is actually being compiled:

```java
package demo;

import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.InterpolatingMicrosphere;
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.UnitSphereRandomVectorGenerator;

public class Library {
    public Library() {
        var d = new InterpolatingMicrosphere(3, 0, 0d, 0d, 0d, new UnitSphereRandomVectorGenerator(3));
        groudebarnismeasicalopmenstear
    }
}
```

Now I get the `gradle build` errors

```
> Task :lib:compileJava FAILED
lib/src/main/java/demo/Library.java:9: error: not a statement
        groudebarnismeasicalopmenstear
        ^
lib/src/main/java/demo/Library.java:9: error: ';' expected
        groudebarnismeasicalopmenstear
                                      ^
```

How can gradle build the first code block successfully even though I'm not specifying the dependencies anywhere? I've tried `gradle clean` and `gradle --refresh-dependencies` many times.

How to reproduce:

```
$ mkdir demo
$ cd demo
$ gradle init

Select type of project to generate:
  1: basic
  2: application
  3: library
  4: Gradle plugin
Enter selection (default: basic) [1..4] 3

Select implementation language:
  1: C++
  2: Groovy
  3: Java
  4: Kotlin
  5: Scala
  6: Swift
Enter selection (default: Java) [1..6] 

Select build script DSL:
  1: Groovy
  2: Kotlin
Enter selection (default: Groovy) [1..2] 

Select test framework:
  1: JUnit 4
  2: TestNG
  3: Spock
  4: JUnit Jupiter
Enter selection (default: JUnit Jupiter) [1..4] 

Project name (default: demo): 
Source package (default: demo): 

Enter target version of Java (min. 7) (default: 20): 
Generate build using new APIs and behavior (some features may change in the next minor release)? (default: no) [yes, no] 

> Task :init
Get more help with your project: https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/samples/sample_building_java_libraries.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
$ rm lib/src/test/java/demo/LibraryTest.java
$ echo "package demo;

import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.InterpolatingMicrosphere;
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.UnitSphereRandomVectorGenerator;

public class Library {
    public Library() {
        var d = new InterpolatingMicrosphere(3, 0, 0d, 0d, 0d, new UnitSphereRandomVectorGenerator(3));
    }
}" > lib/src/main/java/demo/Library.java
$ gradle build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 814ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: Why are you even using gradle if you don't have a build script?

Comment: @aled isn't it (or an equivalent like maven) a huge help for managing dependencies and building large projects?

Comment: I mean why are you executing it before writing the build script if the application needs more than the default?

Comment: @aled because while trying to get familiar with gradle, I just happened to notice this crazy behaviour

Comment: The gradle version I have installed at the moment (4.4.1) is running some task but it is not "building" a project. On my machine it looks like it's running some dummy task. Even if I introduce an error in the source file the "build" still succeeds. What specific version are you running? Also, are you getting an actual build out of this or only the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca gradle 8.1.1 JVM 20.0.1. Mine fails if I introduce an error in the source file. `builds/libs` has a `demo.jar` in it; I don't know how to check if that's the expected/correct build output

Comment: That version on my machine explicitly tells me there's no Gradle build. I cannot reproduce the behavior you're showing. I'm not saying I don't believe you :) I'm just saying double-check your assumptions about what is and isn't present in the directory and the paths you're running this in.

Comment: I re-read my latest comment and it's probably not clear that by "that version on my machine" I mean I installed version 8.1.1 and I still cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca please can you check out my steps to reproduce. I just copy/pasted that from my terminal

Comment: Wait, so you do have a `gradle.build`. You generated it with `init`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I did not know that build.gradle was in lib...

Comment: upvoted because you have pointed out a "stange" (at least not documented) behavior:  the gradle init task will indeed add some hard-coded dependencies to the generated `build.gradle` script,  `commons-math` in "api" scope and `guava` in "implementation" scope . I guess it's done on purpose to show example of api vs implementation concept in the generated skeleton script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `build.gradle` file is actually located in `lib`, it's not top-level.

The `build.gradle` generated by `gradle init` - *library* coincidentally specifies the apache commons math dependency that you're using.